# How to resolve conflicts with conda packages

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I have this Dockerfile and I want to install all the Python dependencies which include opencv-python 4.7.0.68 in the requirements.txt file

```
# PyTorch image
...

RUN pip install -r  requirements.txt
```

However, I am getting this error and I can't seem to resolve the issue except not installing the opencv-python 4.7.0.68

```
55.09 Installing collected packages: voluptuous, tensorboard-plugin-wit, sentencepiece, library, easygui, tensorboard-data-server, safetensors, regex, pyasn1-modules, protobuf, opencv-python, oauthlib, multidict, markdown, lightning-utilities, grpcio, ftfy, frozenlist, entrypoints, cachetools, async-timeout, absl-py, yarl, requests-oauthlib, huggingface-hub, google-auth, aiosignal, torchmetrics, tokenizers, google-auth-oauthlib, diffusers, aiohttp, accelerate, transformers, timm, tensorboard, altair, pytorch-lightning, open-clip-torch
56.38     Found existing installation: protobuf 3.20.3
56.39     Uninstalling protobuf-3.20.3:
58.77       Successfully uninstalled protobuf-3.20.3
58.87   Attempting uninstall: opencv-python
58.87     Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.6.0
58.87 ERROR: Cannot uninstall opencv-python 4.6.0, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by conda.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.2.0-cuda12.1-cudnn8-runtime

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I don't know what other packages and versions you require, but you have mentioned `opencv-python==4.7.0.68`.

`requirements.txt`

```
opencv-python==4.7.0.68
```

Build and check that correct package version is available in running container.

[image]

Comment: I have that package defined in the requirements.txt but I can't install it because `The package was installed by conda` (4.6.0)

Comment: Have you tried my `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt` above? Start with something that works and then adapt to your purposes.